# How can I replay a list of mouse coordinates to reflect the rhythm with which they were inputted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create my own clientside mouse tracker which will send the data to a database, I can get the data, but I'm not sure how I can replay the data in a way that matches exactly how it was originally inputted.

For every 'onmousemove' event I'm saving the coordinates in an array, after every second I take that array and push it into another array.

```
Array(2)[
  Array(34)
  0:{x: 393, y: 176}
  1:{x: 393, y: 175}
  2:{x: 393, y: 176}
  3:{x: 388, y: 182}
  4:{x: 383, y: 189}
  5:{x: 379, y: 195}
Array(6)
  0:{x: 393, y: 176}
  1:{x: 393, y: 175}
  2:{x: 393, y: 176}
  3:{x: 388, y: 182}
  4:{x: 383, y: 189}
  5:{x: 379, y: 195}
]
```

I obviously didn't think this through because my logic falls apart at the replay stage, I thought that I would iterate one of the nested arrays for every second, but this would happen extremely quickly, then I thought about maybe dividing one second by the amount of elements in the array.

Array 1 has 10 elements so a time interval will trigger every 100 milliseconds to move the cursor, this is still not the correct solution because the user might have created all the coordinates in the first half of the second and none in the second half this would cause the replay to lose all genuine user dynamics.

So in what way should I persist the data so that it can be replayed without losing the exact behaviour of the user in the replay process?

React Redux states in combination with this kind of tracker makes it theoretically possible to completely replay a user interaction with the app, this idea fascinates me.

Comment: You can save also timestamp or offset from the last recorded position, that way you don't need to create array every second just one array consisted of every mosemove events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For keeping track of the rhythm/timing, you could just save the timestamp along with the `x`/`y` positions for each event you're tracking, and then calculate the difference between them to "replay" them with the same timing. This would allow you to store it all in one array as well, rather than having to navigate nested arrays.

Actually "replaying" this may be difficult, since as far as I know there's no way to actually force the mouse to a certain position; however, if you just want a visual replay you could simulate it using a mouse icon.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding another value to your array, let's say `time`. Using `Date.now()` you can get the time at which your action was performed. This can also eliminate the array inside an array (unless you needed it for something else)

This way you would get and array that looks like this:

```
 [
   { x: 393, y: 176, time: 1234567890123 },
   { x: 393, y: 178, time: 1234567890125 }
 ]
```

You can then use the delta between 2 time to determine how much time elapsed between these 2 actions.

Comment: So I would take delta of times A and B then wait for that time to expire before moving the 'cursor'  to point B and repeat?

Comment: It would mean that the delta between A and B is the time it took to perform that action. As someone mentioned, you can "replay" it using a cursor icon and just changing its position.