# How to practically replay a list of mouse coordinates after they have been inputted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a continuation of [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956263/how-can-i-replay-a-list-of-mouse-coordinates-to-reflect-the-rhythm-with-which-th).

I have recorded mouse coordinates on the mousemove event with a timestamp, I now want to replay this collection of coordinates and move a mock cursor (img) according to it.

I have tried implementing the solution from the previous thread but I don't know how to practically do it.

This is what needs to happen:

1. Move img to position
2. Take time difference from current position to next position
3. Wait for that amount of time
4. Move img to next position

I have tried working with setInterval and a timeout function but it doesn't work how its supposed to, try out the code and maybe you can come up with a solution.

Only thing you need to run this is an image to act as the cursor.

```
import React from 'react'

import cursor from '../../assets/images/cursor.png'

export default class Tracker extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      tracking: [],
      replay: false,
      replayPoint: null,
    }
  }

  onMouseMove = event => {
    let newArr = this.state.tracking.slice()
    newArr.push({ time: Date.now(), x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY })
    this.setState({ tracking: newArr })
  }

  stopTracking = () => {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
    this.setState({ replay: true, replayPoint: { x: 0, y: 0 } })

    this.state.tracking.forEach(function(p, i, array) {
      let that = this
      if (i + 1 < array.length) {
        let interval = array[i + 1].time - p.time
        setTimeout(function() {
          that.moveCursor(p)
          that.sleep(interval)
        }, interval)
      }
    }, this)
  }

  moveCursor = p => {
    this.setState({
      replayPoint: { x: p.x, y: p.y },
    })
  }

  sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime()
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      if (new Date().getTime() - start > milliseconds) {
        break
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    let cursor = this.state.replay && <Cursor cords={this.state.replayPoint} />

    return (
      <div>
        {cursor}
        <button onClick={this.stopTracking}>Stop tracking</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
  }
}

class Cursor extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { x, y } = this.props.cords
    console.log('move to ' + x + ' - ' + y)
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          src={cursor}
          style={{
            left: x + 'px',
            top: y + 'px',
            position: 'fixed',
            width: '20px',
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```